# Error while installing ubuntu 14.04. Partition problem / no root file system defined

Tags: 14.04

While installing Ubuntu 14.04, getting this error..

> NO ROOT FILE SYSTEM DEFINED. PLEASE CORRECT THIS FORM THE PARTITIONING MENU.

Please guide me how to proceed further. I'm installing inside windows 7 OS.

I have 320 GB disk. C drive is primary of 176 GB n d drive as 99 GB of logical drive. Rest 15 GB I made as unallocated as it was showing primary previously. So i deleted this 15 GB m tried installing. But still its showing error.

Comment: this would help : **http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation**

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

```
gparted /path-to-your-device1 /path-to-your-device2
```

Select a disk device.

Choose: Device → Create Partition Table. The application displays a "Create partition table on /path-to-device" dialog.

Optionally, select a different partition table type from the list.
Many operating systems recognize gpt and msdos partition tables, but do not recognize all types of file systems. This lack of file system recognition means that using a disk without a partition table involves more risk. For example, some operating systems might prompt to format an unpartitioned disk if the file system is not recognized.

You might have overwritten, maybe you can attempt data rescue if needed.